# Delphi 11 TIdHTTP.Get results in Could not load SSL Library

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-11-alexandria

On a blank Delphi 11 project I dropped a button and an TIdHTTP component.

The button attempts to get a .txt file.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Stream: TMemoryStream;

begin
  Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;

    try

      IdHTTPGetProgramUpdateFile.Get('https://www.bookup.com/cowupdates/build129.txt', 
                                     Stream);

    except

      on E: Exception do
        begin
          MessageDlg(E.Message,
                     TMsgDlgType.mtInformation,
                     [TMsgDlgBtn.mbOK],
                     E.HelpContext);
        end;
    end;

  Stream.SaveToFile('downloaded.txt');

  Stream.Free;
end;
```

If the Windows project requests the URL with https then the error is "Could not load SSL Library."

If the project on Windows or Macintosh requests the URL with http then the error is "301 Moved Permanently". (The file is on the web site.)

If the project is run on a Macintosh with https then the PAServer reports the project "is loading libcrypto in an unsafe way."

When running for Windows, the project throws an exception in `IdSSLOpenSSL.pas` with the source code comment:

> an exception here probably means that you are using the wrong version of the openssl libraries. refer to comments at the top of this file.

The comments at the top of the file were not useful to me.

I'm trying to download the contents of a text file from a web site and I know very little about the internet protocols. What am I missing?

Comment: Any reason why you're not using the native HTTP classes?

Comment: There are many existing questions on these errors, why aren't you searching before asking?

Comment: Also, albeit a bit off-topic, in real code you need to protect your object using a `try..finally` block. And typically you should just let the exception propagate (no `try..except`). (And: use absolute paths!)

Comment: @DaveNottage What are the "native HTTP classes?"

Comment: @MikeatBookup Dave is referring to Embarcadero's own [`THTTPClient`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Net.HttpClient.THTTPClient) and [`TNetHTTPClient`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Net.HttpClientComponent.TNetHTTPClient) classes, which use platform-native HTTP functionalities provided by supported OSes (whereas Indy doesn't, it implements HTTP/S manually).

Comment: @MikeatBookup: Probably `TNetHTTPClient`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43153919/delphi-tidhttp-vs-tnethttpclient

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If the Windows project requests the URL with https then the error is "Could not load SSL Library."

You are relying on `TIdHTTP` using Indy's default `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` component, which depends on OpenSSL 1.0.2 library files (ie, `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll`, etc), so make sure you deploy those files with your app, preferably in your app's installation folder.  Or, if needed, Indy does have an `IdOpenSSLSetLibPath()` function you can call at app startup to specify an alternate folder path where the libs are located.

> If the project on Windows or Macintosh requests the URL with http then the error is "301 Moved Permanently". (The file is on the web site.)

`301` is a redirect response. The server is telling you that the URL you have requested is old and the resource is available at a different URL (in this case, it is probably redirecting you to the HTTPS url), which will be provided to you in the `TIdHTTP.Response.Location` property, and in the `TIdHTTP.OnRedirect` event.

If you have `TIdHTTP.HandleRedirects` set to `true` (it is `false` by default) then `TIdHTTP` will automatically re-request the new URL for you.  Otherwise, it will treat the `301` as an error condition, and you will have to manually request the new URL yourself.

> If the project is run on a Macintosh with https then the PAServer reports the project "is loading libcrypto in an unsafe way."

By default, on 'Nix-based systems, Indy attempts to load the OpenSSL library files using unversioned symlinks, and if that fails then it falls back to loading specific versioned library files instead. Using symlinks is not safe because they may map to library versions you are not expecting.  For instance, on modern systems, the OpenSSL unversioned symlinks may map to library files for OpenSSL 1.1.x or later, which `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` does not support (use [this SSLIOHandler](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/pull/299) instead).  Indy has `IdOpenSSLSetCanLoadSymLinks()` and `IdOpenSSLSetLoadSymLinksFirst()` functions that you can call at app startup to prevent Indy from attempting to load symlinks.  Then you can deploy specific versioned library files with your app, or point Indy to a folder where they reside.

> When running for Windows, the project throws an exception in `IdSSLOpenSSL.pas` with the source code comment:
>
> > an exception here probably means that you are using the wrong version of the openssl libraries. refer to comments at the top of this file.
>
> The comments at the top of the file were not useful to me.

You can use Indy's `WhichFailedToLoad()` function after the error occurs to find out whether Indy failed to load OpenSSL because the library files failed or load, or they were missing required function exports.